# Write the longest possible loop

Tags: programming-languages, loops, computer-science

Recently I was asked this question in a technical discussion. What is the longest possible loop that can be written in computational science considering the machine/architecture on which it is to run? *This loop has to be as long as possible and yet not an infinite loop and should not end-up crashing the program (Recursion etc...)*

I honestly did not know how to attack this problem, so I asked him if is it practically possible. He said using some computer science concepts, you can arrive at a hypothetical number which may not be practical but nevertheless it will still not be infinite.

Anyone here; knows how to analyse / attack this problem.

P.S. Choosing some highest limit for a type that can store the highest numerical value is apparently not an answer.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm curious what kind of answers come out of this. I can't help but think back to my Discrete class and learning about the smallest countable infinite set of numbers. +1 good topic!

Comment: Define length.  Time to run?  Number of iterations?

Comment: @Joseph: There is no defined length, time or limit. Its a computer science theory test i think, wherein u need to arrive at the maximum possible number which is not infinite loop.

Comment: @Abhay:  It needs clarification.  In my answer, I listed four possible problems this could be.

Comment: @David: I agree with the possibilities in your answer. But from a computer science perspective the 'Busy Beaver' comes close to an answer. I changed the wording 'programming languages' to 'computational science'. Let me know if the question is to the point.

Comment: Just loop to infinite minus one, of course ;)

Comment: @Abhay "to arrive at the maximum possible number which is not infinite loop" – the fact that you can even write this suggests you have major problems

Comment: @David Heffernan: I asked the creator of this question if its practical. Its not. But this is just a computer science quiz. Given the architecture of the machine, IMHO it is reasonable to expect a value atleast theoretically.

Comment: @Abhay "Given the architecture of the machine". You haven't done this. Anyway, there isn't a largest finite number. Or perhaps you mean something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting into the field of turing machines.

Simply put (lets stay in the deterministic fields...) your computer/machine can be in a finite number of states that are passed during the algorithm. every state is unique and only occours once, otherwise you would by defnition have an endless loop. like "goto".
we can remove that limitation, but it would not make much sense because then a trivial algorithm can be found that always has one more loop runs than every other possible algorithm.

so it depends on the machines possible states which you could naively translate by "its ram".

so the question now is: whats the longest possible loop on a machine that can be in X several states? and wikipedia gives [the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)

Comment: yes, i think this is how i would start to analyse the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Please read up on the Busy Beaver problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver

Comment: but this could also be an infinite loop, so that's not what op wants. But very good answer, +1

Comment: @Oops: "this could also be an infinite loop"?  Really? "The Turing machines in this class must meet certain design specifications and are required to eventually halt after being started with a blank tape" is the quote on Wikipedia.  Is that wrong?

Comment: The Busy Beaver problem allows infinite tape which gives it the ability to have way longer loops with a finite number of states than I think a regular computer can do.

Comment: @munificent: An infinite tape is not the same as non-terminating.  The "infinite tape" is a mathematical formalism that merely removes an arbitrary upper bound.  The fact that the busy beaver algorithms must halt makes them finite.

Comment: Understood. But the reason a Busy Beaver program can run for a fantasticastically long (but not infinite) time with a relatively small number of states is because it has access to as much tape as it needs. Give a busy beaver a finite tape, and you'll find the bounds go way down.

Comment: @munificent: The point is to create the longest-running algorithm.  All algorithms are limited by memory.  Finding a busy beaver that makes maximum use of memory as a large (but finite) tape will be (possibly) the longest-running algorithm that fits in that amount of memory.  The memory limitation doesn't prevent the busy beaver from being a very, very long-running algorithm.

Comment: The Busy Beaver problem is *not* limited by memory. If it was, the problem would be trivial to solve. Saying, "The Busy Beaver problem but in finite memory" is no the Busy Beaver problem than "Traveling Salesman with a max of five cities" is the traveling salesman problem. The memory limitation *does* prevent it from being long-running. With finite memory, the longest program is simply a counter that treats all memory as a single number. That's *fantastically* faster than the Busy Beaver problem.

Comment: @munificent: I'm a little lost.  It seems that  "Traveling Salesman with a max of five cities" actually **is** the traveling salesman problem.   Any finite upper bound on a problem still **is** the same problem.  Square root of *x* is the same problem as square root of 5.  Since the question includes the "considering the machine/architecture" business,  I can't see how anything  could take longer than a busy beaver algorithm with finite memory.

Comment: TSP is NP-hard with complexity somewhere around O(2^n). "TSP with a max of five" is O(1). A program to compute the square root of any given number is a good bit more complex than `void main() { printf("2.23606797749979"); }`. There's one well-known algorithm that takes so much longer than a Busy Beaver with finite memory that no algorithm *can* take longer: the Busy Beaver problem.

Comment: @munificent: Why does TSP jump from O(2^n) to O(1)?  How is TSP not TSP?  I'm lost as to how the complexity magically changes.

Comment: Pass in 5 cities to TSP and how many operations does it perform? Around 32. Now pass in 6: 64. 7: 128. 8: 256. Hence, `2^n`. Now pass in 5 cities to TSPM5: 32. Pass in 6: 32. Pass in 7: 32. 8: 32. 3728146: 32. Beyond 5, the number of operations is constant regardless of the input size. Hence, `O(1)`. Likewise, Busy Beaver with constrained memory is a fundamentally different algorithm with entirely different performance characteristics.

Comment: @munificent: It appears that TSP is always O(2^n).  I don't get why you keep saying that for some values of n it's not O(2^n).  All your examples are O(2^n).  What are you saying?  It both is and is not O(2^n)?  That's very confusing.  Can you clarify how it magically stops being O(2^n)?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to make things any clearer. There are two algorithms. One will find the shortest route through a given series of cities. This algorithm has `O(2^n)` complexity where `n` is the number of cities. Another algorithm will find the route path through the first five of a given series of cities. It has `O(1)` complexity where `n` is the number of cities. They produce different outputs and have different performance requirements. They are fundamentally different algorithms. Is this not clear?

Comment: @munificent: "route path through the first five of a given series"?  Why are we discussing this?  I can't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Because that's exactly isomorphic to the Busy Beaver problem with constrained memory. You cap the memory: you cap the algorithm, and it changes completely.

Comment: @munificent: "you cap the algorithm, and it changes completely."  I still don't see how.  Traveling salesman with n cities is O(2^n). Right? Even if n is 5.  Or 6.  Or 1024, right?  What am I missing?  How does an algorithm's complexity magically change when we put a specific value in for *n*?  I still don't see why O(n) for a specific value of *n* is magically different.

Comment: Yes, TSP is O(2^n). Now let's consider another problem we'll call the Lazy Salesman Problem. The Lazy Salesman will find an optimal route through a set of cities, but he only looks at the first five in the list you give him. Tell him to visit as many cities as you want, but he'll only visit the first five. The LSP *not* O(2^n). It's just O(1). Pass in a million cities, and it takes just as long as if you pass in ten. Once you constrain the set of data the algorithm will work on, it changes fundamentally. When you say "Busy Beaver Problem with finite memory" you're turning it from TSP into LSP.

Comment: @munificent: " When you say "Busy Beaver Problem with finite memory" you're turning it from TSP into LSP.".  I still don't see why.  You're LSP magically removes the O(2^N) complexity in a way that's simply magical.  It seems like finding a route through *n* cities is complexity O(2^n), even if n=5, n=6 or n=1024.  Why does binding n to 5 suddenly change the complexity?   Would setting n=1024 also change the complexity?  Would setting n=1024^1024 also change the complexity?  Why?

Comment: The LSP doesn't find a route through `n` cities. It finds a route through the *first five* of `n` cities. No matter how many you pass in, all but the first five are ignored. `n` here isn't the number of cities the algorithm actually considers, it's (as always) the size of the input provided to the algorithm. The LSP happens to ignore a lot of that input, which is why its complexity is radically different from TSP. That's the same reason that a linear search has different complexity than a binary search: binary search doesn't look at as many input items.

Comment: @munificent: I'm certainly unable to see how "It finds a route through the first five of n cities" comes from "finds a route through n cities where n=5."  I'm really unable to understand why it's so important to keep changing "n=5" to "the first 5 of n".

Comment: This discussion is taking forever. If you're around, I'll be in the SO Tavern chat for the next hour or so. Maybe we can clarify this in realtime.

Comment: @munificent: I apologize for failing to see why to keep rearranging the simple constraints into more complex constraints.  I doubt real-time will help.  It's simply my inability to understand why n=5 is somehow not n=5 but "the first 5 of n" or some other such thing that isn't obvious from n=5.  Real-time won't help.  What would help is some rational reason why n=5 does not mean n=5.

Comment: I think you've got a fuzzy definition of `n`. `n` is always the number of items passed to the algorithm. If we pass 1000 cities to TSP, `n = 1000`. If we pass 1000 cities to LSP, `n = 1000`. The fact that LSP only ever looks at 5 of them is irrelevant. n is only 5 when you pass exactly five cities to the algorithm. Consider an algorithm for finding the first item in a list. If you pass a list of a thousand items to it, you'll agree that `n` is 1000, surely? The reason that algorithm is `O(1)` is precisely because it doesn't need to look at all `n` items, just the first.

Answer (score 1):

The largest possible finite value? As a mathematician, I find that ridiculous. Perhaps the problem could be explained better.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about language limitation, well, some languages define arbitrary-precision integers (like Python and Common Lisp), so you could count up to any number you liked as far as the language goes.  You could easily set it too large for any actual machine, but that's not a language limitation.

As far as counting on actual machines go, it's a matter of the number of possible states.  For each bit you can allocate as a counter (and it doesn't have to be as one data element, since it's real easy to make an arbitrary-length counter), that's two states, so if you had 8G of memory available you could count to something like 2^8G with it.  You could of course use the file system for more counter space.

Or, assuming you're not using physically reversible computation, you could check the minimum energy necessary to flip a bit, divide the amount of energy available (like the total expected solar output or whatever), and get a limit.

There is a limit for Turing machines of specified complexity.  It goes up pretty fast.

There's too many possible answers to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

If "long" means time, the following finite loop should be a good bet:

```
for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < ULONG_LONG_MAX; ++i) sleep(UINT_MAX);
```

Okay this answer is not really serious, but actually my opinion is that the question is totally useless to ask in a job interview. Why? According to S.Lott's answer, this could be about the Busy Beaver problem which is almost 50 years old and is totally unknown because nobody could make use of it in a real job.